# Decision Tree error in Trafo and level in factors

Tags: r, decision-tree

I have this code:

```
mydata= read.csv("/home/file.csv",stringsAsFactors=F)

sapply(mydata, class)
       chr        start         stop       strand   num_probes segment_mean     is_nocnv
```

That return:

```
"character"    "integer"    "integer"  "character"    "integer"    "numeric"  "character"
```

I create my decision tree:

```
set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2,nrow(mydata),replace=TRUE, prob= c(0.7,0.3))
trainData <- mydata[ind==1,]
testData <- mydata[ind==2,]


myFormula <- is_nocnv ~ chr + start + stop + strand + num_probes + segment_mean
albero <- ctree(myFormula, data=trainData)

table(predict(albero),trainData$is_nocnv)
```

And I obtain my first error:

```
Error in trafo(data = data, numeric_trafo = numeric_trafo, factor_trafo = factor_trafo,  : 
  data class “character” is not supported
```

Then there is this code:

```
chr1 <- as.character("chr19")
start1 <- as.integer(284018)
stop1 <- as.integer(58878226)
strand1 <- as.character("*")
num_probes1 <- as.integer(23929)
segment_mean1 <- as.numeric(-0.0142)
testData <- data.frame(chr=chr1,start=start1,stop=stop1,strand=strand1,num_probes=num_probes1,segment_mean=segment_mean1,is_nocnv=as.character(""))

testPred <- predict(albero,newdata= testData)
table(testPred,testData$is_nocnv)
```

Here i obtain my second error:

```
Error in checkData(oldData, RET) : 
Levels in factors of new data do not match original data
```

and

```
Error in table(testPred, testData$is_nocnv) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

Comment: What packages do you use? Try `stringsAsFactors=T` when you import your data, because the model likes `factor` variables and not `character` variables. Your first error occurs because you want to build a model with `character` variables as inputs.

Comment: hi @AntoniosK if i use stringAsFatctor = T the first error is ok. But the second error remains

Comment: Not sure what causes the 2nd error without any data. Looks like your test set has a factor level that doesn't exist in your train set. That's something common if you have a specific level with few observations and they end up in test set (due to change) when you randomly create your train and test sets.